# Does we have this equality $\lim_{n\to\infty}\int_{-a}^a K_n(s)f(s)\,ds=\frac{\lim_{x\nearrow 0}f(x)+\lim_{x\searrow 0}f(x)}{2}$?

Tags: real-analysis, fourier-analysis

I claim that we do have the following equality. And I give my proof. Am I correct?
Let $I=(-a, a)$ be an interval (finite or infinite). Suppose that $\{K_n\}_{n=1}^\infty$ is a positive summation kernel, i.e. it is a sequence of real-valued, Riemann-integrable functions defined on $I$, with the following properties:
\begin{align}&(a)K_n(t)\geq 0,\forall n\in\mathbb N,t\in\mathbb R\notag\\
&(b)\int_{-a}^aK_n(t)\,dt=1\notag\\
&(c)\text{If }\delta>0, \lim_{n\to\infty}\int_{a>|t|>\delta}K_n(t)\,dt=0.
 \end{align}  If $f$ is integrable and bounded on $I$ and the left and right limits exist, say $$\lim_{x\nearrow 0}f(x)<\infty\text{ and }\lim_{x\searrow 0}f(x)<\infty.$$ Then $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\int_{-a}^a K_n(s)f(s)\,ds=\frac{\lim_{x\nearrow 0}f(x)+\lim_{x\searrow 0}f(x)}{2}.$$
Here is my proof:
Let $\lim_{x\nearrow 0}f(x)=L\text{ and }\lim_{x\searrow 0}f(x)=R.$ $\exists \delta_1>0$ such that if $x\in (-\delta_1,0),$ we get  $$|f(x)-L|<\epsilon ,\forall \epsilon>0.$$ $\exists \delta_2>0$ such that if $x\in(0,\delta_2)$, then $$|f(x)-R|<\epsilon ,\forall \epsilon>0.$$ Let $\delta=\min\{\delta_1,\delta_2\},$ then if $x\in(-\delta,\delta)\setminus\{0\},$ we have $$\left|f(x)-\frac{L+R}{2}\right|=\frac{1}{2}|2f(x)-L-R|\leq \frac{1}{2}|f(x)-L|+\frac{1}{2}|f(x)-R|<\frac{\epsilon}{2}+\frac{\epsilon}{2}=\epsilon.$$ Then $$
 \Delta=\int_{-a}^aK_n(s)f(s)\,ds-\frac{L+R}{2}=\int_{-a}^aK_n(s)f(s)\,ds-\frac{L+R}{2}\int_{-a}^aK_n(s)\,ds=\int_{-a}^aK_n\left[f(s)-\frac{L+R}{2}\right]\,ds.$$ We want to show that $\Delta\to 0$ as $n\to\infty.$ Since $f(x)$ is bounded on $I,$ then $\exists M'\in \mathbb R$ such that $$|f(x)-\frac{L+R}{2}|\leq 2M,$$ where $M=\max\{M',(L+R)/2\}.$ Then
\begin{align}
  |\Delta|&=\left|\int_{-a}^aK_n(s)\left[f(s)-\frac{L+R}{2}\right]\,ds\right|\leq \int_{-a}^aK_n(s)\left|f(s)-\frac{L+R}{2}\right|\,ds\notag\\
  &=\int_{(-\delta,\delta)}K_n(s)\left|f(s)-\frac{L+R}{2}\right|\,ds+\int_{(-a,a)\setminus (-\delta,\delta)}K_n(s)\left|f(s)-\frac{L+R}{2}\right|\,ds\notag \\
  &=\lim_{\alpha \nearrow 0}\int_{(-\delta,\alpha )}K_n(s)\left|f(s)-\frac{L+R}{2}\right|\,ds+\lim_{\beta \searrow 0}\int_{(\beta,\delta)}K_n(s)\left|f(s)-\frac{L+R}{2}\right|\,ds\notag  \\
  &\ \ \ \ +\int_{(-a,a)\setminus (-\delta,\delta)}K_n(s)\left|f(s)-\frac{L+R}{2}\right|\,ds\notag \text{ ------- }(1) \\ 
  &\leq \epsilon\lim_{\alpha \nearrow 0}\int_{(-\delta,\alpha )}K_n(s)\,ds+\epsilon\lim_{\beta \searrow 0}\int_{(\beta,\delta)}K_n(s)\,ds+2M\int_{(-a,a)\setminus (-\delta,\delta)}K_n(s)\,ds\notag\\ 
  &= \epsilon\int_{(-\delta,\delta)}K_n(s)\,ds+2M\int_{(-a,a)\setminus (-\delta,\delta)}K_n(s)\,ds\notag \text{ ------- }(2)\\
  &\leq\epsilon+2M\int_{(-a,a)\setminus (-\delta,\delta)}K_n(s)\,ds\notag. 
 \end{align} $\exists N\in\mathbb N$ such that if $n\geq N,$ then $$\int_{(-a,a)\setminus (-\delta,\delta)}K_n(s)\,ds\leq \frac{\epsilon}{2M}$$ $\Longrightarrow$ $$|\Delta|<2\epsilon.$$
Did I make mistakes in (1) and (2) above?

Comment: It is one of the conditions, which I have mentioned.

Comment: Ah OK, missed it. Will delete.

Answer (score 1):

As stated, the result is false. Take $a=1.$ Let $K_n(x) = (n+1)(1-x)^n, x\in [0,1],$ $K_n=0$ elsewhere. Define $f=1$ on $[0,1],$ $f=0$ on $[-1,0).$ We then have $\int K_n f \to 1,$ not $(1+0)/2.$

Comment: This counterexample is quite good, but I still wonder which part in the proof I made a mistake.

Comment: The mistake is claiming $$\frac{1}{2}|f(x)-L|+\frac{1}{2}|f(x)-R|<\frac{\epsilon}{2}+\frac{\epsilon}{2}.$$ If $x<0,$ then you don't have $\frac{1}{2}|f(x)-R|<\frac{\epsilon}{2},$ because that holds for $x>0.$ Similarly for the other way around.